# How can I detect which fields are being tracked by Chatter via REST

Tags: rest-api, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, chatter-rest-api

I need to detect via REST API, which fields have been enabled for Chatter object feed tracking.

Just to be clear it is the setup option found here: **Setup > Customize > Chatter > Feed Tracking**

[image: Feed Tracking for Account]

Finding out whether or not the *object* is enabled is quite easy. This is part of the describe result data when making a request to any objects describe endpoint such as this:

```
/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Account/describe
/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Expense__c/describe
```

This returns JSON where the `feedEnabled` property tells me whether the object has been enabled.

But if you dig into individual fields, they do not appear to have an attribute in their meta-describe attributes that corresponds to feed tracking.

I also don't see an object that appears to hold this data that can be queried. But I'm still looking.

As a fall-back I might consider a solution using Apex, if there is a way to obtain this information there.

Comment: I've not tried but in the Tooling API there is a TrackFeedHistory and TrackHistory on the fields and its REST...

Comment: Hmmm...so long ago...I'm trying to remember if I looked at those. Well...the Chatter Trailhead challenges are already live as of yesterday, so it is too late for now...if we look at improving, I'll look into these then.